# How should I balance two very conflicting peer reviews on a manuscript?

Tags: peer-review

I received reviews for a manuscript that are very conflicting, and I am not sure how best to proceed.

One reviewer states the paper is a great contribution to the field, good length, provides some minor grammatical suggestions, and raises one issue that I can address in the text.

The other reviewer seems to have not understood the paper (which is on me for not making the scope more clear, although Reviewer 1 states the scope exactly in their review and states that they think the paper outlines it well). They state that they don't really see the point of the study and say both that it needs to be made more concise overall but also calls for additional figures, tables, and text in other places.

I am most unsure how to proceed with the length and additional figures/tables part. Any advise on balancing this sort of review?

Comment: This is where I would look to the editors letter. Any clues there on how much weight to assign to the needy reviewer?

Comment: @Dawn No clues from the associate editor, they were pretty vague: 
"A "revise" decision has been made on your manuscript based on my judgement as Associate Editor and on the reviewers' comments. If the revisions that you make are deemed adequate, the manuscript can be accepted. However, acceptance is not guaranteed, especially if major revisions have been recommended."
I was thinking I could reach out to them and ask for a bit more guidance.

Comment: @Sursula-they-That question is somewhat helpful about reaching out to the editor, etc, but doesn't address my specific question about conflicting comments about length and figures/tables, which is why I asked a new question. If the community thinks it is a duplicate though, I understand.